# high availability rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-availability

I am working on deployment strategy and scripts for rails in a secure high availability environment.  Our current scripts are home grown shell scripts.  We would like to use a more standard process.  But...

It's a little difficult for me to believe that anyone with a high availability production environment would run a deployment from an instance of the code tree.  If I am to do that, I would have the code tree there just for the purpose of deploying, because I can't access my production environment from a development environment.

I am not going to use vagrant, because I don't think that is suitable for production.

I am not going to use virtual box, because I don't want the overhead.

I do have a separate plan for how to make the environment highly available, so this question is not about that.

I just need a decent way to do rails deployments into a secure production environment.  And it seems silly to me to have a special instance of the tree for each project on a machine at my colo on my production lAN so that I can deploy to other machines, especially since the deployment will get the version of the app to use from the repository using a tag.

Can anyone help?  Have war stories?  Clear reasons for me to change my opinions?

EDIT:
Per question in comments:

Production has a network layer, which is ssl, firewall, name-based forwarding. App layer is where rails is, and that is accessible only if you are ssh-ed in via the network layer (or vpn-ed in) for production monitoring or administration, but I can not scp or rsync or ssh directly from my development box. The db layer is accessible from the app layer servers.

Thanks!

Comment: "I can't access my production environment from a development environment" - well then, from where do you have access to it?  And where is your repository hosted?  I would highly recommend Capistrano for its flexibility/automation/rollback features, but its unclear to me exactly what your setup is.

Comment: Production has a network layer, which is ssl, firewall, name-based forwarding.  App layer is where rails is, and that is accessible only if you are ssh-ed in via the network layer (or vpn-ed in) for production monitoring or administration, but I can not scp or rsync or ssh directly from my development box.  The db layer is accessible from the app layer servers.

Comment: So what systems have access to the network layer if you can't ssh in personally?  Can you ssh in to a system that does?  And can the network layer access your repo directly?

Comment: I guess the point is that I do not want to open up a hole in our secure production environment so that we can do deploys in a way that does not make sense to me.  Is there some real reason to run a deploy from a development environment?  The current deploy scripts require a person to have sudo on the machine to which they are deploying, and that is it.  Is there no one else who has a secure production environment they can not easily access from their laptop (or someone else can easily access from their laptop)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively new deployment framework for distributed deployments called [Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/).  I've never used it for Rails.  The only thing I've used for large rails deployments is chef, but a friend and I are working on using Juju for some other (jvm) projects, and it is pretty powerful.

Here's [a good tutorial](http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/11/16/deploying-your-rails-application-in-the-cloud-via-juju/) for getting started with rails and juju.

There is a [rails juju charm](https://github.com/charms/rails) that you can find (currently) on github

One of the advantages of juju is that you can have a single server that manages deployments to other servers.  That way you don't have to open up the servers local machines for deployments.

Good luck!